# How to obtain all possible matrices (or data.frames) which have a column less from the original matrix (or data.frame)

Tags: r

How can I obtain all possible matrices (or data.frames) which have a column less than the original matrix (or data.frame)

For example, lets say I have a matrix (or data.frame) `tmp`

```
structure(list(V1 = 1:5, V2 = 6:10, V3 = 11:15, V4 = 16:20, V5 = 21:25), 
.Names =  c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

How can I efficiently get: tmp[  , - 1], tmp[ , -2], tmp[ ,-3], tmp[ ,-4], and tmp[ , -5]

At the moment I can think of:

```
 llply(list(1,2,3,4,5), function(x) {tmp[[x]] <- NULL; tmp})
```

This can be also done using `lapply`. Is there a better or more intuitive and efficient way of doing this, especially when `tmp` is matrix (without doing `as.data.frame(tmp)`)?

Thank you in advance for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
lapply(1:ncol(tmp),function(i)tmp[,-i])
```

Works both for matrices and data frames.

Can't see how you can do that more intuitively than that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `lapply` with simple indexing :

```
R> tmp <- matrix(1:10000,nrow=100,ncol=100)
R> lapply(1:ncol(tmp), function(i) {tmp[,-i]})
```

Maybe there is a more efficient solution, but I think that the main problem with this method is that if your original matrix has a big number of columns (say *n*) the result of the `lapply` function will be huge (as it will be a list of *n-1* matrices) and you may run out of memory to handle it.